# Writing a Sys::Getpagesize Perl module for system call getpagesize (man page GETPAGESIZE(2))

Tags: perl, system-calls, rhel, perl-xs

I have been tasked to write a Perl module that requires that I use Perl XS.  I have not ever used Perl XS but I have looked at the documentation here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlxs.html and it looks like I will need the C source code for the `getpagesize` system call. I tried looking for `getpagesize.c` via `yum` like so ...

```
$ sudo yum provides */getpagesize.c
```

... but I do not seem to have any RPMs that would provide `getpagesize.c`.

Can anyone out there help me out of the ditch I seem to have driven into?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think you need the source code to the `getpagesize` function?  You just link to the system's version.  I haven't tried it, but something like this should work:

```
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"
#include <unistd.h> /* man 2 getpagesize says to use this */

MODULE = Sys::Getpagesize PACKAGE = Sys::Getpagesize

int
getpagesize()
```

But in this case, you shouldn't need to write XS at all.  `man 2 getpagesize` says "Portable  applications  should employ `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` instead of `getpagesize()`."

Perl's standard [POSIX](https://metacpan.org/module/POSIX) module has `sysconf` already:

```
use POSIX qw(sysconf _SC_PAGESIZE);
print sysconf( _SC_PAGESIZE );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should simply be able to do:

```
getconf PAGESIZE
```